# Running a visual studio .exe in ubuntu

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ubuntu-16.04

I am in a introductory c++ class and the teacher gave us a .exe from his visual studio code to show us what our program is supposed to look like.  My question is can I run this on the command line.  I have problems with wine and would rather not use it (i.e. wine xxx.exe).  I have tried ./xxx.exe.  All the questions I have seen deal with actual programs running a real game or something so I don't think this is a duplicate but if it is please point me to the correct place.

Comment: Apart from recompiling, wine is the best option as far as I know.

Comment: this is not really c++ related

Comment: If you have a windows license running windows under Virtual Box should also work. However `wine` will be the simplest method and it should work pretty well for most command line windows programs. I can run a most of my Qt based windows executables under `wine` with no issues at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The binary format for linux and windows is different, so there *must* be a middleware that will know how to call a windows binary in linux, this currently is wine, if it's a console windows application it could also be dosbox.

You already said that you had problems with wine and prefered not to use it, sorry, you have to. executing a binary from windows in linux without wine is like trying to opening a wine bottle in linux, linux is not a bottle opener, not it's windows - binary format compatible.

Another thing you could ask for your teacher is the source code for his application, you could try to compile under ubuntu (if he used standard c++) and run there.

Comment: k i guess i will just have to live with wine